# How to get wifi hardware information on Android

Tags: android, wifi

Following will give me basic wifi information, but I want the hardware information:

**WiFiScanReceiver.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WiFiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "WiFiScanReceiver";
    systemInfo systemInfo;

    public WiFiScanReceiver(systemInfo systemInfo) {
        super();
        this.systemInfo = systemInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> results = systemInfo.wifi.getScanResults();
        ScanResult bestSignal = null;
        for (ScanResult result : results) {
            if (bestSignal == null
                    || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level,
                            result.level) < 0) bestSignal = result;
        }
        String message = String.format(
                "%s networks found. %s is the strongest.", results.size(),
                bestSignal.SSID);
        Toast.makeText(systemInfo, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() message: " + message);
    }
}
```

**systemInfo.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.MemoryInfo;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class systemInfo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "WiFiDemo";
    WifiManager wifi;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    TextView textStatus;
    Button buttonScan;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Setup UI
        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        // Setup WiFi
        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        // Get WiFi status
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        textStatus.append("\n\nWiFi Status: " + info.toString());
        // List available networks
        List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
            textStatus.append("\n\n" + config.toString());
        }
        // Register Broadcast Receiver
        if (receiver == null) receiver = new WiFiScanReceiver(this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
        MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
        long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
        System.out.println("availableMegs:::::::::::" + availableMegs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "On Click Clicked. Toast to that!!!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonScan) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick() wifi.startScan()");
            wifi.startScan();
            String ab = getInfo();
            System.out.println("CPU INFORMATON:::::::::::::\n" + ab);
            textStatus.append("CPU INFORMATON:::::::::::::\n" + ab);
        }
    }

    private String getInfo() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("abi: ").append(Build.CPU_ABI).append("\n");
        if (new File("/proc/cpuinfo").exists()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                        "/proc/cpuinfo")));
                String aLine;
                while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(aLine + "\n");
                }
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**permissions are**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

This gives me basic wifi information .But I want the hardware information ..

One important difference is the CPU architecture. Although almost all Android devices use ARM CPU, it comes with different versions, including armv5, armv5te, armv6, armv6 with VFP, armv7, armv7 with VFP, armv7 with neon etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is *how to obtain the hardware information about the WiFi chip*, then answer is simple: Android does not provide this kind of data, except of MAC address (which, btw, is not really the hardware information).